# Issue with asp.net api routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I have api Item controller with method `GetQuery`

```
 public async Task<IList<Domain.Item>> GetQuery(
            long? genderId , 
            long? locationId, 
            int pageIndex = 1,
            int  pageSize = 10 
            )
```

I want to call this method without any parameters and I get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the appropriate action then:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Domain.Item))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetQuery()
```

Parameters form part of the matching pattern used when routing tries to figure out what action to execute. Simply create the appropriate action with the appropriate signature, and then use that new action to execute your other action or a shared method.